# IOS10 , Xcode 8.2 Google Admob issue

Tags: swift, xcode, admob

I has follow up `Google Admob` get start to create a `Xcode` project with `Swift3` and `FireBase` link
but always get the error :

 `class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate { Thread 1: signal SIGABRT }`

has run the pod update more time,

My code : Appdelegate.swift

```
//I has import Firebase and GoogleMobileAds
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        FIRApp.configure()
        //GADMobileAds.configure(withApplicationID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~1458002511")
        return true
    }
```

ViewController.swift

```
//I has import Firebase and GoogleMobileAds

    let kBannerAdUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"

    class ViewController: UIViewController, GADBannerViewDelegate, GADInterstitialDelegate {

        @IBOutlet weak var bannerView: GADBannerView!
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            self.bannerView.adUnitID = kBannerAdUnitID
            self.bannerView.rootViewController = self
            self.bannerView.load(GADRequest())

            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry All, I found the answer, I forgot link my project to Firebase.
forgot add GoogleService-info.plist to my project.